# Rails - Posting a Boolean (true or False) and updating the DB in the controller

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

in my Rails 3 App, I'm posting with jQuery the following:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/topics/read_updater?&topic_id=101&read=true
```

In my controller:

```
  def read_updater
      current_user.topics.where(:topic_id => params[:topic_id]).update_all(:read => params[:read])

    render :json => {:status => 'success' }
  end
```

params[:topic_id] works great, but params[:read] is inserting empty values in the DB, even though jQuery is posting either a true or false. Ideas? I want rails to update the DB with either true or false.

Thanks

Comment: do you mean `params[:topic_id]` is working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe `update_all` isn't parsing passed string? `params[:read]` is a string:

```
params[:read]
=> "true"
# or
=> "false"
```

So maybe it is trying to save a string to this column and that's why you have problems.

Try this line:

```
current_user.topics.where(:topic_id => params[:topic_id]).update_all(:read => true)
```

And see if it is working. If yes, then replace `:read => params[:read]` with something like `:read => params[:read] == 'true'`.

I also hope that you've checked how `params` hash looks in this controller. If not, just put:

```
logger.debug params.inspect
```

at the begining of `read_updater` method and check logs if everything is fine.